# regex: Matching parts of a string when the string contains part of a regex pattern

Tags: python, regex

I want to reduce the number of patterns I have to write by using a regex that picks up any or all of the pattern when it appears in a string.

Is this possible with Regex?

```
E.g. Pattern is: "the cat sat on the mat"

I would like pattern to match on following strings:
"the"
"the cat"
"the cat sat"
...
"the cat sat on the mat"
```

But it should not match on the following string because although some words match, they are split by a non matching word: 
    "the dog sat"

Comment: You are not clear on whether you want the "the" to match if followed by "dog", or not.

Answer (score 7):

This:

```
the( cat( sat( on( the( mat)?)?)?)?)?
```

would answer your question. Remove "optional group" parens "(...)?" for parts that are not optional, add additional groups for things that must match together.

```
the                       // complete match
the cat                   // complete match
the cat sat               // complete match
the cat sat on            // complete match
the cat sat on the        // complete match
the cat sat on the mat    // complete match
the dog sat on the mat    // two partial matches ("the")
```

You might want to add some pre-condition, like a start of line anchor, to prevent the expression from matching the second "the" in the last line:

```
^the( cat( sat( on( the( mat)?)?)?)?)?
```

**EDIT:** If you add a post-condition, like the end-of-line anchor, matching will be prevented entirely on the last example, that is, the last example won't match at all:

```
the( cat( sat( on( the( mat)?)?)?)?)?$
```

Credits for the tip go to [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490762/regex-matching-parts-of-a-string-when-the-string-contains-part-of-a-regex-patter#490785). Thanks!

The post-condition may of course be something else you expect to follow the match.

Alternatively, you remove the last question mark:

```
the( cat( sat( on( the( mat)?)?)?)?)
```

Be aware though: This would make a single "the" a non-match, so the first line will also not match.

Comment: -1: would have partially matches in "the dog sat on the mat", whereas the user explicitly required NO match...

Comment: Ok... I cancel my -1;) If you add a '$' at the end of your regexp, it works :)

Comment: I asked him if he requires a non-match, I don't think he was too explicit about it, but if he does, your solition is, though complex, the only way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

It could be fairly complicated:

```
(?ms)the(?=(\s+cat)|[\r\n]+)(:?\s+cat(?=(\s+sat)|[\r\n]+))?(:?\s+sat(?=(\s+on)|[\r\n]+))?(:?\s+on(?=(\s+the)|[\r\n]+))?(:?\s+the(?=(\s+mat)|[\r\n]+))?(:?\s+mat)?[\r\n]+
```

Meaning:

- I want "`the`" only if followed by "`cat`" or end of line
- then I want "`cat`" (optional) only if followed by "`sat`"
- and so one
- followed by and end of line (which ensure to not match partial "the cat walk...")

It does match

**the cat sat on the mat**
**the cat**
**the cat sat**
the cat sat aa on the mat (nothing is match either)
the dog sat (nothing is matched there)

---

On second thought, [Tomalak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490762#490794) is simpler (if fixed, that is ended with a '$').
I keep mine as a wiki post.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, factored in! :-) If no post-condition can be defined, your regex is still the only way to do it. Switching to wiki mode might have been a bit premature. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you know the match always begins at the first character, it would be much faster to match the characters directly in a loop. I don't think Regex will do it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would be easier and more logical to think about the problem a little differently..

Instead of matching the pattern against the string.... how about using the string as the pattern and looking for it in the pattern.

For example where

string = "the cat sat on"
pattern = "the cat sat on the mat"

string is always a subset of pattern and is simply a case of doing a regex match.

If that makes sense ;-)

Comment: And what if the pattern is "the (cat|dog|bird|fly) (sat|stood) on the mat"?